# Series and Sequences. In an arithmetic series T3=-2 and T9=28. How many terms of this series are required to give a sum of 1092

Tags: sequences-and-series

Q.In an arithmetic series T3=-2 and T9=28. How many terms of this series are required to give a sum of 1092.

I have made an attempt at the question. By using the Sn formula, iam having trouble with understanding HOW this question is done.
Could someone please advise or instruct me on how to do this question.

Thankyou for taking the time to read and help a curious student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you know that $T_n = a + (n-1) d$. This means you have two equations:
$$-2 = a + 2d\\
28 = a + 8d$$
which you can use to calculate $a$ and $d$.

Once you have that, you know that $$\sum_{n=1}^N T_n = \frac{T_{n} + T_1}{2}N = \frac{N}{2} (a + d + a + (N-1)d) = \frac{N(Nd + 2a)}{2}$$
and just set that to $1092$ to find the correct $N$.

Comment: Sorry, but isnt the formula Tn=a+(n-1)d ?

Comment: It can be both. Both formulas give you an arithmetic series, but I will fix my answer.

Comment: I edited my answer to the more proper definition of arithmetic series...

Comment: im not particularly sure with how to do the second part of your explanation

Comment: Hahaha, after intense thinking. I got the answer. Thankyou

Comment: Did you calculate $a$ and $d$ yet?

Comment: yes i got a and d  a=-12 d=5

Comment: Well, then you are looking for the value of $N$ for which $$\frac{N(5N - 24)}{2} = 1092$$ You will get a value of $N$ from this equation.

Comment: yes i worked it out

Comment: Ah. Sorry then, I missed the point when you said you got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set $T_{n}=a+bn$.

Then $30=T_{9}-T_{3}=6b$ so $b=5$.

Then $-2=T_{3}=a+5\times3$
so $a=-17$.

Found is now that $T_{n}=5n-17$ so that $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(5n-17\right)=\frac{5}{2}n\left(n+1\right)-17n$.

Now solve the equation $\frac{5}{2}n\left(n+1\right)-17n=1092$

Answer (score 0):

difference between terms is 5.
implies a=-12,d=5, sn=1092

solve n by
     sn=n/2*(2(-12)+(n-1)5)

1092=n/2*(-24+5n-5)
1092=n/2*(5n-29)

now solve quadratic equation 5n^2-29n-2184=0
it's bit tedious. but solved.